# How to make video play only when a button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that inside of it has a `<video autoplay> <source src='myvid'> </video>` and by default the div has a `display ='none'` on css. I am adding an event listener of click on the div and once its clicked i am changing the display none to display block.

the problem is that the video plays automatically when the site reloads and not when the button is clicked. basically i want the video to play only when the div is display ='block'.  How can i do that in Javascript?

Comment: have you tried removing the `autoplay` attribute ? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes and if i do that the video doesnt play at all

Comment: @enhzflep Sorry if you think so. I feel like the I have already listed the only code that is needed, if you read what i wrote. But anyway i will have it as a tip for next time

Comment: @Whyudodis - . Since my comment has been deleted, it's obviously been judged inappropriate. I'm sorry I did not understand this before writing it. It was penned (keyed!) with the following page in mind. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Remove the `autoplay` attribute
- Use JavaScript to play the video using a custom button and the [.play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) method

```html
<video id="video"> <source src='myvid'></video>
<button id="play">PLAY</button>
```

```js
document.querySelector("#play").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("#video").play();
});
```

If you don't want a custom button (not clear from your question) than you could provide the browser default by using the [`controls` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

```js
const EL_video = document.querySelector("#video");
const EL_play = document.querySelector("#play");

EL_play.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const isPaused = EL_video.paused;
  EL_video[isPaused ? "play" : "pause"]();
  EL_video.classList.toggle("u-none", !isPaused);
});
```

```css
#video {width: 300px;}

/* Utility classes: */
.u-none {display: none;}
```

```html
<button id="play">Toggle &amp; play</button><br>
<video id="video" class="u-none">
  <source src='http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

try addind an `onclick` attribute to the div like this:

```
<div onclick="play_video();">
```

Or you can create a button:

```
<button onclick="play_video();">play the video</button>
```

Then, create the javascript function like this:

```
function play_video()
{
  document.getElementById("id_of_the_video").play();
}
```

Comment: If hopefully you don't use inline `style=""` attributes, the same way you should not use inline `on*=""` handlers attributes. JS should be in one place only and that's your `script` tag or file.

Comment: Why? I do use inline `style=""` sometimes. It is more convenient for those little usages